# Count child object node values and add them to parents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm using angularJS. I have some data inside of my $scope. What i want to accomplisch is that the values of the child object nodes are calculated and added on the parent object nodes.

I have made some code and it's working but only for the **last** parents

```
$scope.data =
    [
        {
            name: "active",
            value: null,
            children:
            [
                {
                    name: "vast actief",
                    value: null,
                    children: 
                    [
                        {
                            name: "gebouwen",
                        value: [13, 540, 195, 200],
                        children: null
                        },
                        {
                            name: "tereinen",
                        value: [25, 20, 25, 50],
                        children: null
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "vlottend actief",
                    value: [215, 230, 245, 500],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "bewegend actief",
                    value: [134, 135, 136, 137],
                    children: null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "stilstaand",
            value: null,
            children:
            [
                {
                    name: "vast stilstaand",
                    value: [2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "vlottend stilstaand",
                    value: [2150, 2300, 2450, 5000],
                    children: null
                },
                {
                    name: "bewegend stilstaand",
                    value: [1340, 1350, 1360, 1370],
                    children: null
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

This is the code i've created. With this code it will loop untill the `children` property in `null`, then it will look if there is a data property, and if there is it will count the values on the same position of its parent array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.labels.length; i++){
    var label = $scope.labels[i];
    calcParent(label);
}


function calcParent(label) {
    if (label.children != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < label.children.length; j++) {
            if (label.children[j].data) {
                if (!label.data){
                    label.data = [];
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < label.children[j].data.length; k++) {
                    if (!label.data[k]) {
                        label.data[k] = 0;
                    }
                    label.data[k] += label.children[j].data[k];
                }
            } else {
                var parent = label.children[j];
                    calcParent(label.children[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that it only does the calculation on the **last** parent all parents above don't see their child values yet because they don't excist yet.

I need to have something that first goes down the tree and after that goes up again. How can i accomplish that.

### **EDIT**

So i have made a plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYXx3oP9i6vPzUbedghH?p=preview), but now i lost it... It works in the plunker.

To give you an idea, in my app "active" is only counting the values of "vlottend actief" & "bewegend actief", and **not** "vast actief".

"vast actief" is only counting his child "tereinen" and **not** "gebouwen".

I just copied my code so it's very strange that it works in plunker.

Comment: If they don't exist yet then you need to do this when they do exist. Question is confusing. A [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) would help

Comment: Ok i will provide a plunker!

Comment: I don't know why but it does work in plunker... See my edit please above.

Comment: for the part that you state `don't exist yet` I assumed children were being populated using `$http` for each parent . Can't help if can't reproduce problem

Comment: No, what i mean with `don't exist yet` is that in above example i think `active` will try to count all the values of `vast actief`, `vlottend actief` & `bewegend actief` but at the time it tries to count, `vast actief` is still `null` because it is a parent to of `gebouwen` & `tereinen` and `vast actief` has to go through the same function first, No?